# Window resizes lag/CPU spikes when compositor running

Tags: graphics, window, opengl, picom

I run Gentoo with i3 and the picom compositor. I installed the alacritty terminal to give a try, and noticed that when picom is running, the terminal lags when rapidly resizing the window - rather than a smooth motion, it stutters. It also spikes a CPU core, under the alacritty process. When I kill the picom process though it works smoothly. I get this with other windows, but it's far far worse with alacritty, likely because it's a completely GPU rendered terminal, although I'm not certain on the specifics of what's going on.

I have a Ryzen 5 and GTX960 (with nvidia drivers), so hardware isn't the issue here. Is this a bug in picom, or a possible misconfiguration in my graphics libraries or the compositor?